# How to unflip the print of the coresponding printer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, printers

How can I unflip the print of the printer? Here is my code:

```
 {
      "name": "Printer",
      "response_timeout":500,
      "network_address": "182.145.1",
      "offset_x": 5,
      "offset_y": 3
    }
  ],
  "print_config": {
    "size_x": 100,
    "size_y": 50,
    "flip": ["horizontal"
    ],
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you tried so far?

Comment: for example the print is like this abcde. what i want to happen is to print it in edcba

Answer (score 0):

I guess by unflip, you mean to make it vertical?

If that's the case I think just accessing the value is enough.

print_config.flip[0] = 'vertical'

I accessed it like that because the flip attribute is an array

**EDIT:**
To reverse a string just do this

```
let str = 'abcde';
str.split('').reverse().join('')
// Output: edcba
```

Comment: for example the print is like this abcde. what i want to happen is to print it in edcba

Comment: Hi there. Apologies for the late response, but has your question been answered?